# create table in oracle in .net with parameter error

Tags: oracle, parameters, oledbdataadapter

I am using Oracle 10 G database

```
    Drop Table yassin; 
Create Table yassin as Select  
              sad_gen.key_dec,
              sad_gen.key_year,
              sad_gen.sad_typ_proc,
              sad_gen.sad_asmt_nber,
              sad_gen.key_cuo,
              sad_gen.sad_reg_nber,
              sad_gen.sad_reg_date,
              sad_gen.sad_asmt_date,
              sad_gen.sad_dec_date,
              sad_gen.sad_exporter,
              sad_gen.sad_stat_val,
              sad_gen.key_nber,
              sad_gen.sad_itm_total,
              sad_gen.sad_pack_total,
              sad_gen.sad_consignee,
              sad_gen.sad_cty_1dlp,
              sad_gen.sad_tra_cty,
              sad_gen.sad_cty_expcod,
              sad_gen.sad_cty_destcod,
              sad_gen.sad_tod_cod,
              sad_gen.sad_cur_cod,
              sad_gen.sad_tot_invoiced,
              sad_gen.sad_tra_cod1,
              sad_gen.sad_mot_bord,
              sad_gen.sad_cuo_bord,
              sad_gen.sad_total_taxes,
              sad_gen.sad_reg_year,
              sad_gen.sad_asmt_year,
              sad_gen.sad_rcpt_nber,
              sad_gen.sad_rcpt_date,
              sad_gen.sad_loc_goods,
              sad_gen.sad_lop_cod,
              sad_gen.sad_whs_time
              FROM   sad_gen
              WHERE  
                    sad_gen.sad_num=:X
                    AND   sad_gen.lst_ope='U';

                    SELECT  *  from yassin;
```

When I use it and `SET parameter X VALUE IN .NET with OleDbDataAdabtor`

The error I get is `ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number`

this is my function.
Query is upper is query
Para is sturct that keep parameter values
    public DataTable GetTable(String Query,AsycudaParameter[] Para)
    {

```
    OleDbConnection c = new OleDbConnection(ConnectionString);
    c.Open();

    OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(Query, c);

    for (int b = 0; b < Para.Length; b++)
    {
        if (Query.Contains(Para[b].name))
        {
            if (Para[b].Type == TypeCode.String)
            {
                da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter(Para[b].name, OleDbType.VarWChar));
                da.SelectCommand.Parameters[da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Count - 1].Value = Para[b].value.ToString();

            }
            if (Para[b].Type == TypeCode.Decimal)
            {
                da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter(Para[b].name, OleDbType.Decimal));
                da.SelectCommand.Parameters[da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Count - 1].Value = decimal.Parse(Para[b].value.ToString());

            }
        }
    }
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);


    c.Close();


    return dt;
}
```

Comment: Can you show the .Net code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle does not allow bind variables in DDL.  So you cannot use a bind variable in a `CREATE TABLE` statement.  If you really want to create a table, you would have to hard-code the query in the DDL (that is, you would probably need to use string concatenation to build the DDL statement rather than using bind variables).

Why would you want to create a table at runtime in your application in the first place?  That is generally not something that you would want to do-- tables should be created when you are installing your application, not at runtime.

Comment: @ParvizGta - Why do you want to create the table at runtime in the first place?  My first advice would be not to create the table in the first place since runtime DDL is almost always a design error.

Comment: @ParvizGta - I don't understand the comment.  You need to create a table at runtime because you have a query editor?  I don't see the relationship between the two.